# Fixing inaccessable usb flash drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive, formatting

This problem first appeared when a friend of me tried to copy some files from my computer.
The transfer of 29GB stopped and the process could not be aborted, it just froze!
So I pulled out the usb flash drive during a transfer. Which is probably what caused this. But there should be a way to format it or something like that, right?

Picture of how "My Computer" looks:

[image]

Comment: Right-click Format?

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck with either a Linux live disk or if available a computer running a Linux Os.  Plug the affected flash into the Linux machine, copy whatever you need or can get from it, and format the drive to make it usable again on a Windows machine if you need it urgently.  A favorite is Linux Mint.